# How to accept dynamic json response and add one key-value to that object and return that same JSONObject from the spring boot controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

My controller is receiving post request as dto object and my dto has one Object array which is used to get the array of json objects, I have to add one key-value to each json object in that array and return it back.

dto class:

```
public class FileProcessDTO {

    private String module;
    private Object[] data;

    public String getModule() {
        return module;
    }
    public void setModule(String module) {
        this.module = module;
    }
    public Object[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Object[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

below is controller method

```
@PostMapping("/processData")
    public FileProcessDTO processFileData(@Valid @RequestBody FileProcessDTO fileProcess) throws JSONException {

        String module = fileProcess.getModule();
        Object[] objects= fileProcess.getData();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(fileProcess.getData());

        FileProcessDTO fileProcessDTO = new FileProcessDTO();
        fileProcessDTO.setModule(module);


        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                jsonObject.put("status", true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                jsonObject.put("status", false);
                jsonObject.put("error", e.getMessage());
            }


            objects[i]=jsonObject;

        }
        fileProcessDTO.setData(objects);

        return fileProcessDTO;
    }
```

and below is the data passed in post request from client

```
{
"module" : "assignment",
"data":[
    {
        "name": "chandan",
        "age":"27"
    },
    {
        "name": "Yo",
        "age":"26"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jo",
        "age":"25"
    }
]
}
```

In above objects of *"data"* array keys and values will be different in different request(may be in next request *"name" and "age"* will changed).

Below I am getting error.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.crisil.apg.service.dto.FileProcessDTO["data"]->org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject[0])
2019-04-17 12:04:14.002  WARN 10808 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator
```

I also tried to change line in controller method as below but, its not as json response.

```
objects[i]=jsonObject.toString();

//below is response
{
    "module": "assignment",
    "data": [
        "{\"name\":\"chandan\",\"age\":\"27\",\"status\":true}",
        "{\"name\":\"Yo\",\"age\":\"26\",\"status\":true}",
        "{\"name\":\"Jo\",\"age\":\"25\",\"status\":true}"
    ]
}
```

Kindly suggest the possible code to make it work.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String as request body then convert the string to JSONObject and do the processing.

```
@PostMapping(value="/get",consumes={"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(@RequestBody String req){

        //String to JSON Object
        JSONObject obj= new JSONObject(req);
        JSONArray arr=(JSONArray)obj.get("arr");

        //Adding ID to JSON ARRAY
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
            JSONObject ob=(JSONObject)arr.get(i);
            ob.append("id", "id-"+i+1);
            arr.put(i, ob);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(arr.toString(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating above issue with the input you mentioned above, Instead of any error, I got below response on postman:

```
{
"module": "assignment",
"data": [
    {
        "empty": false
    },
    {
        "empty": false
    },
    {
        "empty": false
    }
]
```

}

Logs on my console :

```
2019-04-17 13:24:30.128 DEBUG IND-PBHUITE
            --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : POST "/processData/", parameters={}
2019-04-17 13:24:30.129 DEBUG IND-PBHUITE
            --- [nio-8081-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public com.noobcompany.metrostation.model.FileProcessDTO com.noobcompany.metrostation.controller.MainController.processFileData(com.noobcompany.metrostation.model.FileProcessDTO)
2019-04-17 13:24:30.130 DEBUG IND-PBHUITE
            --- [nio-8081-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [com.noobcompany.metrostation.model.FileProcessDTO@36c525]
2019-04-17 13:24:30.130 DEBUG IND-PBHUITE
            --- [nio-8081-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-04-17 13:24:30.131 DEBUG IND-PBHUITE
            --- [nio-8081-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [com.noobcompany.metrostation.model.FileProcessDTO@f12f53]
2019-04-17 13:24:30.132 DEBUG IND-PBHUITE
            --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                : Completed 200 OK
```

I am using SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE with RestController and using below dependency for JsonObject

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
```